# HX711 with NodeMcu

Tags: nodemcu, arduino-pro-mini

I am trying to make a scale that measuring weight. In internet i did some researches so i got some questions.
I have this module as a HX711 [image: HX711 Module]

And square 3 wired loadcells( Red,White,Black Wired).

My mcu is Noedmcu V3. When i check from the Visual Studio Code, it says Adafruit Huzzah. This MCU's operation voltage is 3.3v and got ESP8266EX chip.

Some Hx711 modules (ex. sparkfun red board) got VDD pin for logic level. But my module has not. Can i operate this hx711 and loadcell with 3.3 volts?

If i cant, i can use 5volts for excitation voltages but communication will be on 5Volts. My mcu operating on 3.3volts. can i add voltage divider to  DT,SCK pins to regulate voltage around 3.3volts? Is it proper solution?

Or if you have any hint about that, can you share with me?

Comment: Vdd pin is for a power connection, not for a logic signal .. it can also be labeled as Vcc ... use the datasheet to determine the required power supply voltage

Comment: My hx 711 has no vdd. Only has vcc. In sparkfuns hook up guide  They said :
**Note: VCC is the analog voltage to power the load cell. VDD is the digital supply voltage used to set the logic level. PRO TIP: In many cases, you can just short VCC and VDD together. If your microcontroller uses 3.3V logic however, you'll want to connect VCC to 5V and VDD to 3.3V.**
But my question is I have 3.3volt mcu and hx 711 wants 5volt. Can i use voltage divider for DT and SCK lines to decrease voltage to 3.3 volts.

Comment: i have the same issue. tried modifying the board to separate VCC and VDD (they are connected by a copper trace hidden under the chip) but it did not work. It seems the chip does not care for VCC pin (pin 1 on datasheet) and only listens to VDD